# skip next sheet once activesheet is deleted vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to validate something in each sheet.
If the sheet contains the required info, it's kept, otherwise deleted. But my problem is, once the sheet is deleted focus goes automatically to the next sheet. hence, when the code hits the next sheet it actually skips one sheet in middle.

I have tried the below code :

```
Sub filterdelete()

Dim current As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rowN As Integer

Set current = ActiveWorkbook
On Error Resume Next

For Each sht In current.Worksheets
If sht.Name <> "hiddensheet" Then

With sht
    .Select
    .Range("A1").Select
End With

rowN = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If rowN = 1 Then ActiveSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next sht

End Sub
```

I tried `GoTo`, also. But it is deleting every sheet. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the worksheets in your workbook in reverse order so that deleting a sheet does not result in an unwanted behavior.

Try something like this:

```
For i = current.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
    // your code here
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem and helping out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a counter variable in your loop and go backwards.

Also, use `Long` rather than `Integer` in case you have more rows than latter can handle.

```
Sub filterdelete()

Dim current As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rowN As Long, i As Long

Set current = ActiveWorkbook

For i = current.Worksheets.Count To 1 step -1
    If current.Sheets(i).Name <> "hiddensheet" Then
        With current.Sheets(i)
            rowN = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            If rowN = 1 Then .Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, nothing will happen here unless you add "Step -1" to the initial line of the for-loop. ;-)